# problem parsing xml with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to parse some xml using simplexml and php...it's being returned to me from a service like so:

```
<DMResponse><Code>2</Code><Description>Your request was successfully received You will        receive notification once the process has been completed.</Description><ResultData><Explanation>     The job name is 578bbn004 </Explanation></ResultData></DMResponse>
```

I pasted this from the .net panel in firebug.

This is how I'm trying to parse is using php:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print 'xml ' . $result . ' xml';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
$code = $xml->code;
echo $code;
```

$result is deinfitely populated...I get it back in the print statement above....it contains the xml structure I've posted.

The error I'm getting is 'String could not be parsed as XML'. I don't understand why it's doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);` ... I've never done it the way you're doing it. That's not to say that it won't work, though.

Edit: If `simplexml_load_string()` doesn't work, your string may contain some (nonprintable) invalid characters or something like that.

Comment: you can check your XML here : [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

Answer (score 1):

To print your SimpleXML Object, you have to use `$xml->asXML()` (to print into a file `$xml->asXML(file_name)`).

If you still have an error :
What is print when you add this code just after `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);`
 ?

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($xml);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```